# How to Fix "Extra horizontal line" in details section

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

I have web based application using Visual Studio 2019 Preview with SAP Crystal Reports 2016 Support Pack 7. I have created a simple report by adding Box object in details section and add vertical and horizontal lines for making table look. All fields in the details sections have checked "Can Grow" property. But in viewing report in Report Viewer, it is showing one extra line at the last row of each page.

Could it be possible to suppress the last additional line before page break through some formula?

The horizontal line property is also checked to "Move to Bottom of Section when Printing"

[image]

Report Design
[image]

OutPut

[image]

Comment: Suppress it with formula, checking for last record?

Comment: Remove the box and use just lines (top, left, right, without the bottom).

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, it is also observed that extra line appears at the last record of each page. Could it be possible to suppress the last before page break through some formula?